# How to start an activity inside any layout, android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have created a an activity named Example which have 3 LinearLayouts . I want to start an activity.  So I used the following lines of code

```
Intent jumpToStationModule = new Intent();
jumpToStationModule.setClassName("com.xxx", "com.xxx.Test");
startActivity(jumpToStationModule);
```

Test is another activity. As a result of the above code a new activity is called in new page. But I want to get the same resule or start the activity inside 2nd layout of Example class.

How to achieve this.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ActivityGroup` to achieve this.

Check for samples where you can add multiple activities to an **ActivityGroup**.

Comment: Do you have any link to refer?

Comment: Well you get samples once you start googling with the above keyword. Here is one using Tabs.  http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265265/android-using-activitygroup-to-embed-activities