# How to embed a MapActivity into another Activity with content on the top and the bottom?

Tags: android, android-activity, activitygroup

I have the Activity ONE with a header and some content on the top of the activity, and some content on the bottom of the activity.

I want to embed a MapActivity TWO on the Middle part of the Activity ONE.

It is possible? How to do it?

I'm checking ActivityGrup documentation and some questions like this: [android: using ActivityGroup to embed activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265265/android-using-activitygroup-to-embed-activities) but i can't find the way to achieve my needs.

Thanks

Comment: why dont u just use map activity and use relative layout to put whatever content you want over the map...shud do it i guess...

Comment: Maybe [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) is what you need.

Comment: i need to do just what i explained, it's a must for my app generator problem. I can't do it with relative layouts

Comment: also, Fragments require API Level 11 or greater, and this app must work in android 1.5....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply impossible to achieve it, i must move all the content from Activity A to activity B (map)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). They're available via [compatability package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to support API level 4 and up. There's lots of good tutorials on Fragments if you google it.

Comment: i need to use this app on Api LVL 3 (1.5), i can't use fragments and compatibility packages